# WPF-I have circle plotted point in XL

Tags: wpf

I have a three point circle points in XL/Report.With the help of saved circle point in Xl want to draw the same circle in WPF canvas.Is any body has any idea ,how we can draw the circle if we know the circle points.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in support for this that I know of.  I'm afraid you will have to do the math yourself.  This site will give you the equations you need. 
http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/08/draw-a-circle-through-three-points-in-c/

Once you have the center, width, and height, you can use the WPF [Ellipse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.ellipse(v=vs.110).aspx) to render it to your canvas.